# Preventing anchor from jumping on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently using 'smooth scroll' on my wordpress page, and I'm attempting to have the page smoothly scroll to the requested section when coming from an external link (using anchors ( `#portfolio`)from there I want the page to start at the top and THEN scroll to the portfolio section.

What's happening is it briefly displays the 'portfolio section' (anchor jump) and THEN resets to the top and scrolls down.

#### Code

```
$(function() {
    $('.menu li a').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
    var target = $(this.hash);
    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
    if (target.length) {
        $root.animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top - 75
        }, 800, 'swing');
            return false;  
            }
        }
    });
});
```

#### page load

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
if (location.hash) { // do the test straight away
    window.scrollTo(0, 0); // execute it straight away
    setTimeout(function() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0); // run it a bit later also for browser compatibility
    }, 1);
}
var urlHash = window.location.href.split("#")[1];
if (urlHash && $('#' + urlHash).length)
    $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#' + urlHash).offset().top - 75
    }, 800, 'swing');
});
```

How do I prevent the 'jumping' that seems to happen on page load?

#### HTML - nav links (using dummy links)

```
<a href="link.com/#portfolio>portfolio</a>
```

#### HTML - divs

```
<div id="portfolio></div>
```

Comment: the set timeout is making it jump to the top after the other code fires...

Comment: The problem is that `link.com/#portfolio` has meaning to the browser -- open in this location.  You can't change the browser so it starts in this location and then runs your jovascript.

Comment: Hi Hogan, I've seen this done before. Obviously it wasn't done using the method I'm doing, is there anyway around this? My Google has been failing me all morning. Is there some type of work around that I'm missing? Thanks for responding to my question.

Comment: Also if this is the best I'll be able to do, then please let me know. I just want to make sure there aren't any alternatives.

Comment: Jumping to the element based on location.hash upon page load is the default browser behavior, I don't think there is anything you can do to override it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can circumvent the browser behavior by changing the anchor so that it carries some additional text that will be unique to the page visit. In the example below, I've added the first six lines to your function to set the AnchorSeed variable, and then I've used that variable where you assign the urlHash variable:

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
    var AnchorSeed = new Date() * 1;
    $( ".AnchorUpdate" ).each(
        function() {
            $( this ).attr( "id", this.id + AnchorSeed );
        }
    );
    if (location.hash) { // do the test straight away
        window.scrollTo(0, 0); // execute it straight away
        setTimeout(function() {
            window.scrollTo(0, 0); // run it a bit later also for browser compatibility
        }, 1);
    }
    var urlHash = window.location.href.split("#")[1] + AnchorSeed;
    if (urlHash && $('#' + urlHash).length)
        $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#' + urlHash).offset().top - 75
        }, 800, 'swing');
});
```

And you'll need to add the AnchorUpdate class to any page element that you might jump to, so that the jQuery routine can find it and update its id with the AnchorSeed value. In this case, we know that "portfolio" is such a link, so it would be modified as:

```
<div class="AnchorUpdate" id="portfolio></div>
```

The effect of this is that the id will change from "portfolio" to something like "portfolio1382124849780" (depending, of course, on the time stamp when the page was loaded).

Because the id "portfolio" won't exist when the page finishes loading (even though it is part of the source HTML), the browswer shouldn't bounce to it.

I used JavaScript entirely because I didn't know if you had access to server variables. If you do, I think they might be a preferable solution, as the code will be more readable. You might use a page counter variable, or simply a server-side timestamp, if possible.

**Edit:**

In the comments you mentioned that this was working for external links, but that it broke internal links. I don't have time to set up a test right now, but I think it would work to add a jQuery routine to update those internal links similar to what is being done above. For example, your internal link is:

```
<a href="#InternalLink">Jump to Internal Link</a>
```

You might give it a different class indicating that it needs updating:

```
<a class="InternalLinkUpdate" href="#InternalLink">Jump to Internal Link</a>
```

And then trigger a similar modification of that class using jQuery:

```
$( ".InternalLinkUpdate" ).each(
    function() {
        $( this ).attr( "href", $( this ).attr( "href" ) + AnchorSeed );
    }
);
```

(Since I'm not able to copy from working code at the moment, I might have made a punctuation error or such in the above -- but it shouldn't take too much tinkering to get it to work properly.

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for your response. Will try it and report back!

Comment: Hi Joe, it doesn't seem to be working. As a matter of fact it breaks the scroll functionality when coming from another page. It still works on the home page though. I see what you are trying to do though I'll tinker with it to see if I can get it to work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's odd. You don't say which browser you're testing with -- but it worked for me in Chrome and Firefox. (I wasn't able to test Internet Explorer for reasons unrelated to the script, and I don't have Safari installed.)

Comment: Hi Joe, I'm using the latest version of Chrome. So you're saying that when you tested it, it would not jump and after the page loaded it would scroll to the selected section? If that's the case it might be an error on my part.

Comment: Yeah -- that was my experience. But I don't have any guess as to why our versions of Chrome would behave differently.

Comment: Maybe I did something wrong, can you tell me what html element .AnchorUpdate applies to just to makes sure I'm understanding it's use correctly?

Comment: Oh, man, I omitted that section from my answer! That might very well be the reason that you're not getting the same results, and I'm really sorry for my careless oversight. "AnchorUpdate" is a class that you need to add to your anchor. I've edited my answer to include this information.

Comment: Hi Joe, it does work! There is still a 'jump' but it does seem to be functioning properly. If you want to have a look visit: sanjay.dmediastudios.com. The only issue I'm having is the smooth scrolling doesn't work on the home page because the section ID's don't match the hash in the URL. Did you also come up with a solution to work around this in your example? I'll tinker but I was curious. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I'm not following the issue: If hash doesn't match any ID, it seems like there would be (A) no bounce and (B) nothing to smooth-scroll to. In that case, wouldn't it just load at the top of the page?

Comment: (But if you got it to work, have I earned a "correct answer"?)

Comment: Oh yes, for sure Joe. What I'm saying is let's say my portfolio link is <a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a> when you first load up the website. The window load function kicks in so <div id="#portfolio"> is now <div id="#portfolio9999"> which doesn't match the linked anchor. Does that make any sense? Your answer is correct and it functions correctly. I appreciate that but I'm starting to wonder if I might be better off using the scrollTo plugin - unfortunately I haven't been able to confirm if it works with anchor links and I'll just end up running into the same issue.

Comment: I'm terrible at explaining things but let's just say it works coming from an external link but does not work when you initially load the home page (not coming from an external link)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39835/discussion-between-jasenmp-and-joe-derose)

Comment: I get it, now. I added an edit that I think will resolve that issue. And yeah, I'll follow up in chat.