# Anchor Link across pages

Tags: hyperlink, tags, anchor

I have a brainscratcher that has left me stumped, so I'm hoping one of you fine people can help me.

Am in development on two different sites, both of which I am trying to use page jump/anchor tags between pages to link to specific content.

The jumps work fine on the page, but if I try to link to an anchor on a different page, it jumps to the appropriate spot for a second or two, then reloads back to the top of the page. I've stripped out any scripts and stuff that I thought could be conflicting or causing the page to reload without any success.

Anchors throughout page setup like this:

```
<h2 id="#anchor">Anchor</h2>
```

Nav jumps on same page work fine:

```
<a href="#anchor">Anchor</a>
```

Nav to jumps from different page do NOT work:

```
<a href="index.php#anchor">Anchor</a>
```

Is there a different or better technique when trying to anchor to spot on different page?

example: http://www.designdesignonline.com/dev/CCEDC/index.php#events

Thanks!

Mark

Comment: Have you tried removing that little, floating "top" link It acts like when it is first loaded, it jumps to the top of the page.

Comment: mrunion - yes I've tried to remove that without any luck. thanks for the suggestion. I have no idea why something this simple is not working. it is also happening on a different site I am working on. very frustrating

Comment: it is definitely an issue with scripts loading after the page jump and resetting the page to the top. I found this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19453813/preventing-anchor-from-jumping-on-page-load which seems to be a fix, though it isnt working for my implementation... some of the scripts on my page take a bit to load, so I think there needs to be some sort of delay -- any thoughts anyone??

Answer (score 0):

mayb you can try this jquery script, which i tried and worked for me

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var hash = '#'+window.location.hash.substr(1);//get the hash from your url
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
    }, 'slow');
});
```